# How to do Typing Replay in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering how typeracer is doing this kinda words reply with also mistakes made while typing I am confused and I have no Idea how to do this in JavaScript

[image: demo]

Comment: There are loads of plugins like Typewriter.js to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hundreds of plugins available out there. One simple way is to use something like this:

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
  loop: true
});

typewriter.typeString('Hello World!')
  .pauseFor(2500)
  .deleteAll()
  .typeString('Strings can be removed')
  .pauseFor(2500)
  .deleteChars(7)
  .typeString('altered!')
  .start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TypewriterJS/1.0.0/typewriter.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you share any code without any plugins

Comment: @Nane The code is very simple. Check out the source: [`typewriter.js`](https://github.com/tameemsafi/typewriterjs/blob/master/typewriter.js). It's pure JavaScript. Not even jQuery. **So do you mean writing clean, object oriented, well tested code is wrong?**

Comment: @Nane Sure, do you understand JavaScript? Check out the source and ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: You Know I got Some Clear Picture . ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `typed.js` and pass your saved strings to it.

Link:

http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Comment: It would be more useful if you share any code without any plugins